# Is it method overloading when having arguments in another order?

Tags: java

According to the definition of method overloading is, creating two methods of the same name with different parameters. But if I change the order in which I give argument then will this also be method overloading?

```
class Overloading{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(calculateScore("Aniket", 200));
        System.out.println(calculateScore(100, "Aniket"));
    }
    public static int calculateScore(String name, int score){
        return score*1000;
    }
    public static String calculateScore(int score, String name){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: Yes,  Compiler doesn't know the behavior of parameter order.

Comment: Yes it is called as method overloading. But in practical is has no significance. You always design a method for a given set of parameters what needs to happen irrespective of the sequence of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The basic element of overloading is to reuse a method name, but making changes to the argument list.

You see, the compiler doesn't understand that your second example "reorders" arguments. Because that requires an understanding of meaning. The compiler doesn't care about that. It only cares about the types and order of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Method Overloading is a feature that allows a class to have more than one method having the same name, if their argument lists are different.

**In JAVA have Three ways to overload a method**

In order to overload a method, the argument lists of the methods must differ in either of these:

1. Number of parameters.
   For example:

   `add(int, int);`
   `add(int, int, int);`
2. Data type of parameters.
   For example:

   `add(int, int);`
   `add(int, float)`
3. Sequence of Data type of parameters.
   For example:

   `add(int, float)`
   `add(float, int)`

*In your case you follow 3 no type.*

for more details [method-overloading](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/)